# Is it possible to see the actual pom.xml executed, including parent dependencies/plugins?

Tags: maven

I need to extract a project from a repository which uses several layers of parent projects. Every parent project adds some dependency or plugins or properties. This is becoming a nightmare as I'm not able to build any more the project, once I've manually added pieces from parent projects.
Is there a way to create a list of all dependencies/plugins/properties which are linked by a single pom.xml so that I can build a portable, single Maven project?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the effective pom (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/effective-pom-mojo.html) that is a kind of merge with all parent POMs.

This is useful to understand the complete list and configuration of plugins.

Whether this helps you to build a "portable" Maven project, I don't know. Without the appropriate Maven repositories with all the plugins, dependencies and so on, Maven will not build.

Answer (score 1):

Base concept of Maven is CoC (Convention over Configuration). Maven has a SuperPOM and all model is inherited from that. SuperPOM is located in maven-model-builder jar. Here is the source https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.2/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html

Each Maven goal is using a *merged* model called effective pom. The help plugin has effective-pom goal which displays the full model including parent model(s) and SuperPOM.

So the answer is just run: `mvn help:effective-pom` command to see actual model.